# Why does xubuntu 14.04 request a reboot on every start?

Tags: upgrade, updates, xubuntu

Since installing xubuntu 14.4, I have often found that the update manager insists a reboot is required even if no upgrades were performed. This seems to be because /var/run/reboot-required and reboot-required.pkgs are not removed during a successful reboot.

As an  example, today I had a notification from the update manager that upgrades were required. It listed a couple of non-kernel packages (python and something else) and the xubuntu base system, which included some kernel updates.

I applied the non-kernel parts and was then prompted only for the base system update.

I applied the base system update and noted

```
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 32 Mar 24 09:07 reboot-required
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 52 Mar 24 09:07 reboot-required.pkgs


    reboot-required

    *** System restart required ***

    reboot-required.pkgs

    linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic
    linux-base
    linux-base
```

I then allowed update manager to restart the machine. After rebooting, the files above were unchanged.

I did find

Mar 24 09:19:28 magrat cron[1149]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)

in the syslog.

I do have other problems on this machine so this might be due to some other failure - notably, modem-manager and network-manager sometimes reboot constantly (though this did not happen on this occasion).

I see I have a couple of votes for this question. How common is this problem ?

Comment: what does this one tells you `apt-cache policy linux-headers-uname -r` you have to put uname -r inside with quotes like ` `